# Unable to compare props on componentWillRecieveProps dispatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have an infinite loop, while its doing what I want it to, fetches my updated data without refresh its extremely slow as its processing over and over.

I have read a few things and tried a check to see if props have updated but cant get it right...

My infinite loop...

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    whenGapiReady(() => {
        const { Id } = this.props;
        this.props.fetchFileUploads(Id)
    });
}
```

tried to change it to:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.Id !== this.props.Id)
    dispatch(this.props.fetchPlayerFileUploads(Id))
}
```

without success, its not doing anything now. I've missed out the gapi as I could add this back in either.

Any assistance of what this should be to stop the loop! Also saw componentDidUpdate should be used as componentWillReceiveProps is being depreciated but I will take anything at the moment.

**EDIT**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    whenGapiReady(() => {
        const { Id } = this.props;
        if(nextProps.Id === this.props.Id) {    
            this.props.fetchFileUploads(this.props.Id)
        }

    });
}
```

The above still loops endlessly...?

Comment: You misspelled the method name the second name, it's `Receive`, not `Recieve`

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and you should avoid using it... More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating

Answer (score 0):

You need to spell `Receive` correctly in the refactored code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
//              ^^
    if(nextProps.Id !== this.props.Id)
    dispatch(this.props.fetchPlayerFileUploads(Id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(nextProps.Id === this.props.Id) {    
            this.props.fetchFileUploads(this.props.Id)
        }
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` will be invoked everytime, and `nextProps.Id` will always equals to `this.props.Id` and hence the infinite loop, you can instead store the Id to state and improve your comparison from there instead